# Arduino ESP8266 ESP-01S GET command

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial, http

Looking for some help on this please. It is a little long winded, but the point of it is I cannot retrieve a string response via my ESP8266 ESP-01S.

I connect my ESP to my Ardiuno using `SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3)`.

I can quite happily send POST and GET commands to my server and process the request server side. This is done through the AT sequence below. My server uses a REST API to receive the request and responds with a simple string (for example 'HELLO'). If I attempt the same client side functionality through C# code or Python on my Pi I receive the response from the server no problem. But on my Arduino the response is always 32 when reading via `ESP.read()` (which I believe is in bytes and signals end of data). I have also tried `esp.readString()` and `esp.readStringUntil('\n')` all with no luck.

Is it not possible to access the response sent back to the ESP using my approach?

I see many examples go down the route of programming the ESP directly. I'm not really looking to do that on this attempt as I am creating some basic Arduino tutorials for family and friends and would prefer to not add that complexity.

Result server response

```cpp
esp8266.println(postRequest);
while (esp8266.available() > 0) {
  Serial.println("." + esp8266.readString() + ".");
}
```

So I guess in short, am I wrong in expecting the

```
//* AT SEQUENCE*
AT
AT+RST
AT+CWMODE
AT+CWJAP
AT+CIPMUX
AT+CIPSTART
AT+CIPSEND
```

```cpp
// CREATE DATA

String data = "=DATA1";

// POST

String postRequest =
  "POST " + URI + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
  "Host: " + HOST + ":" + PORT + "\r\n" +
  "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
  "Content-Length: " + String(data.length()) + "\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
  "\r\n" +
  data;

// GET

String postRequest =
  "GET " + URI + "?data=" + data + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
  "Host: " + HOST + ":" + PORT + "\r\n" +
  "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
  "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
  "Content-Length: " + String(0) + "\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
  "\r\n";
```

Comment: the host header value should not contain port

Comment: @Juraj [That's not true.](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) It's not needed only if it's the default, but even then it's nothing wrong having it.

Comment: Those AT commands are missing arguments. 32 is the ASCII code for a space character. The HTTP server's first character of the response should be "H". Neither your POST or GET request have the proper format for the parameters. GPIO3 is a hardware serial's RX pin.

Comment: thank you, @gre_gor. now I regret I was lazy to open the RFC

Comment: Juraj. Thanks, I understand. Although what is RFC?
@gre_gor, thanks for your response but I'm pretty new to this and what you've said is above my head. I've followed other tutorials (my project is a hybrid of many of them) to get here. Do you know what arguments I am missing? As I seem to have included enough to covert sending data to my server?

Comment: gre_gor corrects me with a link to RFC 2616 (HTTP protocol description). RFC is "Request for Comments" It is a way how standards are maintained at "Internet Engineering Task Force" organization